# How do I turn simple TypeScript types into a markdown table?

Tags: typescript, markdown

I'm writing docs for a library and would like to find a way to turn my `props` into a simple markdown table. Every example I've seen so far feels too complex, and creates a whole docs website for me. I just want to loop over some files that have types and turn them into tables.

Is there a way to turn this:

```js
type Props = {
  /*
   * this is a required color!
   */
  color: string
}
```

into this:

```
| Prop  | description  | type  | Required  |
|---|---|---|---|
|  color | this is a required color!  | string  | yes |
```

...which looks like this when printed from markdown:
[image: Example markdown table]

Thank you!

Comment: take a look at this project: https://typedoc.org/

Comment: It may be overkill, but to write your own such utility it would be a good idea to start with the Typescript [Compiler API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API)